# When a customer applies a non applicable coupon, he/she doesn't receive any message. WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

What can I do to have my site give a message to a customer when he/she applies a coupon that's not applicable, for example, the coupon applies when the order amount is greater than 100, and the order is 80.

The customer doesn't receive any message

Thanks in advance

Rafael

Comment: in woocommerce on the cart page if you try to apply a coupon without enough amount user get this message "The minimum spend for this coupon is 100,00€. " Are you using tierce plugin to manage coupons?

Comment: By default Woocommerce displays always an explicit error notice when a coupon is not applicable on cart or on checkout pages… So your problem can come from your theme, a third party plugin or some customizations made by you.

Comment: I'm not using any special plugin, and I'm using a free WoCommerce them named WooShop Lite, but I'll change it to some other theme to verify if it still happens. Thank you for answering

Comment: after changing the theme, things worked. Thank you